# How to keep a maximum of 79 characters per line in case of Python list comprehensions?

Tags: python

I have function which consists of 1 line. It is something like:

```
return [item for item in list if something_very_long and something_else_very_long] == []
```

How is it most appropriate to separate this statement to adhere to [PEP-8 guidelines of keeping a maximum of 79 characters per line](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id13)? I couldn't find an example like this in PEP-8 documentation.

Comment: Is your return statement correct? You are comparing it using `== []` at the end.

Comment: @Aditya: this is a perfectly fine return statement. It returns either `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers say you should rewrite your list comprehension to a normal loop. It's much easier than that, and you can keep your list comprehension.

You can split wherever you want, it's the same as a statement with parentheses.

```
# Splitting too much just for the sake of example
return [item for item in list if 
        something_very_long and 
        something_else_very_long] == []
```

Answer (score 2):

I voted to close. This is really not about Ubuntu. Just in case you need an answer quickly: don't use a list comprehension if it is too complex. Just try.

```
original_li = [1,2,3,4,5]
new_li = []
for itm in original_li:
     if condition1 and condition2:
         new_li.append(itm)
```

or if the conditions are still too long:

```
original_li = [1,2,3,4,5]
new_li = []
for itm in original_li:
     if condition1:
         if condition2:
             new_li.append(itm)
```

Now you have the list you need. You could wrap this up in a function of course.

Comment: The question is perfectly valid and on-topic here. Will he get a better answer elsewhere? Maybe. Doesn't make it off-topic here.

Comment: @Seth So if I have a question about developing quantum physics algorithms it is also on-topic here? So we mass-close relevant bug reports for ubuntu, but anything that can be done with a computer (read with ubuntu) is on-topic here?

Comment: To a certain extent, yes. Development on Ubuntu is clearly mentioned in the [help] as on-topic.

Comment: @Seth Indeed, "Development **on Ubuntu**". This question could perfeclty be about development on windows. It is just a general development question. Nothing to do with *on Ubuntu*. But hey, you're the mod...

Comment: I'm not sure if that was supposed to be sarcastic or not, but we have always allowed python questions here, as long as the OP is using Ubuntu. If you want to cast a close vote, go right ahead. Sometimes development questions get closed. If they aren't too Ubuntu specific they usually don't get reopened either. It's a fine line and you have to walk it gracefully ;)

Comment: I wasn't being sarcastic. I already voted to close before answering. A thin line indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It is same as

```
   var1=[]    
    for item in list:
        if something_very_long and something_else_very_long:
            var1.append(item)
    if var1: return var1
```